# How to find the first li elment's div

Tags: jquery

I have something like this

```
<ul id="someul">

<li id="one"> Alpha </li>
<li id="two"> Alpha </li>
<li id="three"> Alpha </li>
<li id="four"> Alpha </li>
<li id="five"> Alpha </li>

</ul>
```

What is the jquery way of finding the first li's div value??

Thanks

Comment: `$('#someul > li:first').text();`

Comment: @Matt but instead of text I think he's looking for the id. Try `.attr('id')`

Comment: You can't. None of your `<li>` elements have a `<div>` in them.

Comment: @JustinNiessner it was a trick question, damn ;)

Comment: Ha ha thats not tricky. I was hasty

Comment: I get a value when i use .text() but i get "undefined" if I use .attr('id')

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the id name, do this:

```
$('li:first').attr('id');
```

the value inside of the li can be

```
$('li:first').text(); 
//or
$('li:first').html(); //This is if you want to get everything from inside.
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you don't have a `div` but you can use `first` - http://api.jquery.com/first/

```
 $('#someul li').first().text();
```

Or you can use:

```
$('#someul li:first').text();
```

However `.first()` appears to be faster:

http://jsperf.com/jstest453534

http://jsfiddle.net/eRCGG/

Answer (score 0):

You could use eq(): { zero indexed }

```
$('#someul > li:eq(0)').text();
//or
$('#someul > li').eq(0).text();
```

Still to get the first li:

```
$('#someul > li').get(0).innerHTML; //same as: $('#someul > li:eq(0)').html();
//or
$('#someul > li')[0].innerHTML;
```